# Build a Turing Machine that counts a's and b's

Tags: binary, automata, turing-machines, automaton, jflap

Im trying to design a Turing Machine that takes as input a word formed
by symbols of the alphabet Σ = {a, b} and counts, in binary, the occurrences of symbol a and
the occurrences of symbol b. The final contents of the tape must correspond to the number of
occurrences, in binary, of symbol b, the symbol $, the number of occurrences, in binary, of
symbol a, and then the input string. The final tape should be (number of a's in binary)(th symbol"$")(number of b's)(original string of as and bs)

I was trying to build it but I dont see how can I give the outputs in binary [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlyNR.png)

UPDATE: I've managed to build one that counts a's and b's but by putting a 1, can someone help me make it count in binary instead of in units?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvOwJ.png)

Comment: You have here an example on how to binary add them: http://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/uriyxivgsr . Just do compile and put 1011#10 as example in the load box and click play.